# breeze merge server entities

Tags: typescript, breeze

Here are the main pillars of my problem:

- I have implemented a request-response service layer over http. That
  is a request (object) is sent to server, there it is processed, and
  then a response is sent to the client (TypeScript/javascript).
- Both the request object and the response object may contain breeze
  entities.
- After receiving the response from the server, if there are
  also breeze entities contained in the response, I need to update the
  client cache (entity manager).
- The controller taking care of the
  request processing is marked with [BreezeController], so the entities
  are just like breeze expects them to be. The request and responses
  are themselves NOT breeze entities.

I tried to find a method somewhere in breeze (entity manager?), where, if I pass a list of entities retrieved from server, these are used to update the local cache, but I did not find any. After studying the source code, I did some changes in the breeze library, where I exposed the MappingContext internal class and did the following (TypeScript code):

```
public processEntityRequestAsync<TResponse>(request: requestModel.RequestBase): Q.Promise<TResponse> {
  var promise = this.requestProcessor.processRequest<TResponse>(request);
  var processedPromise = promise.then(r => {
    // TODO everything in this method is a hack using internal things from breeze
    // to update the entities after getting them from server
    var updatedEntities = <any[]>(<any>r).UpdatedEntities;
    if (updatedEntities) {
      var dataService = <breeze.DataService>(<any>breeze.DataService).resolve([{
        serviceName: this.manager.dataService.serviceName,
        adapterName: "WebApi",
      }]);
      var mappingContext = new (<any>breeze).MappingContext({
        query: null, // tells visitAndMerge that this is a save instead of a query
        entityManager: this.manager,
        mergeOptions: { mergeStrategy: breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges },
        dataService: dataService,
      });

      // Note that the visitAndMerge operation has been optimized so that we do not actually perform a merge if the 
      // the save operation did not actually return the entity - i.e. during OData and Mongo updates and deletes.
      updatedEntities = mappingContext.visitAndMerge(updatedEntities, { nodeType: "root" });
    }
    return r;
  });
  return processedPromise;
}
```

NOTE: the <any> conversions are used to bypass the Typescript type checking and use breeze internals.

This works, however I do not like that I have to use breeze internals AND that I have to modify the library for this purpose. Is there a better way to achieve my target?

Comment: I have a similar problem, there's a small section on at the end of [this][http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-depth] breeze documentation page which might help. However I tried that approach unsuccessfully because I got some errors with the merging process, but it worth taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question but take a look at the discussion of the JsonResultsAdapter: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-service-data-mapping

The idea is that a *JsonResultAdapter* can be used on the client to coerce any json data into entities that will be merged into the *EntityManager*.

Comment: This is true, however I have a list of true Breeze entities which I would like to import in the client cache using the WebApi Json adapter and also using all the features that breeze has. As I can see, the merge is not trivial at all, so why not use your implementation, which is *safe* from my point of view.

Comment: The jsonResultsAdapter does not handle merging, it simply tells Breeze how to convert your json objects into entities.  Merging is provided by breeze AFTER this step. And it is not that difficult to implement a jsonResultsAdapter.  Take a look in the source, most adapter will be less that 30 lines of code.